# Fetching Wrong Data MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Table Which has a column test_id i need To Fetch Data Which is not Equal To **t-0105,t-0120,t-044,t-063,t-064,t-068,t-072** but Query Fetching all data.

```
select * from test_name where test_type='p' and test_id NOT IN ('t-0105,t-0120,t-044,t-063,t-064,t-068,t-072') and test_list='tt' and test_name like '%aptitude%' and published=1 order by id asc
```

Comment: add quotes on each string in `Not In` not as a whole

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You put the single quote `'` as wrong. In your query `IN` condition takes all values as a single string. you should add it as shown below.

```
select * from test_name where test_type='p' and test_id NOT IN ('t-0105','t-0120','t-044','t-063','t-064','t-068','t-072') and test_list='tt' and test_name like '%aptitude%' and published=1 order by id asc
```